# Remote debug inside server

Tags: python, ssh, server, pycharm, remote-debugging

I need to ssh into a server and debug a python code running inside a docker. Now, usually I use pycharm IDE to remote debug a server or a docker, but I have no idea how to debug a docker inside a server. How can I accomplish that?